# Unable to display related products using React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working on "React native",Right now i am displaying list of proudcts,So Right now whenever i click on any product then  details of that product is displaying,Now i want whenever i scroll (left to right) on screen then other related products should display,How can i do this ? Here is my current code

```
const route = useRoute()
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const { id } = route.params
  console.log(id)
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [])

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(productsApi)
    //console.warn(response)
    setItems(response.data.data)
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn(error)
    }
  }

  const render_Item = (item) => {
     if (item.id === id) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}  >
        <Image source={{uri:item.image}} style={{width:150,height:150}}/>
           <Text style={styles.title} >{item.title}</Text>
        </View>
      )
     }
    else {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image source={{uri:item.image}} style={{width:150,height:150}}/>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
        </View>
      )
    }
  }

  return (

    <View style={{
      backgroundColor: "#fff",
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "center",
    }}>
      <FlatList
        data={items}
        // renderItem={({ item }) => <SlideScreen title={item.title} />}
        renderItem={({ item }) => render_Item(item)}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        snapToAlignment="start"
        decelerationRate={"fast"}
        snapToInterval={Dimensions.get("window").width}
        horizontal
      />
    </View>
  )
}

export default Splash;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: Dimensions.get("window").height,
    width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#3B5323",
    borderColor: "#000",
    borderWidth: 2,
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
  title: {
    color: "#fff",
    fontSize: 20,
  },
});
```